# Django redirect URLs in modal forms

Tags: python, django, redirect, popup, bootstrap-modal

I am new with Django so I created a `delete_orders` modal form and now I want to redirect to the true path after deleting the order.

My `views.py` is something like:

```
def deleteOrder(request, order_id):
    order_item = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    customer = order_item.customer.username

    url = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    url_path = parsed_url.path

    if '/panel/profile/' in url_path:
        url_path = '/panel/profile/' + customer

    if request.method == 'POST':
        order_item.delete()
        return redirect(url_path)

    context = {'order_item': order_item}
    return render(request, '', context)
```

And my `urlpatterns` is:

```
path('<int:order_id>', views.deleteOrder, name='delete_order'),
```

I want to know if it is a good practice to do the job or we have some other standard solutions?

Answer (score 0):

By passing the name of a view and optionally some positional or keyword arguments; the URL will be reverse resolved using the reverse() method:

```
def my_view(request,order_id):
...
return redirect('deleteOrder', order_id=order_id)
```

Documentation for more information :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples